# Evaluating zero set $Z_{R}(f)$ as a line, the union of a line an a surface, ...

Tags: differential-geometry

The zero set is defined as:

$$Z_{R}(f) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : f(x)=0\}$$

[In this post its claimed](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/the-cayley-salmon-theorem-via-classical-differential-geometry/) that the zero set of $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$$ is a line

while the zero set of

$$f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_3^2 + x_2^2 - x_2^3$$

is the union of a line and a surface.

How are these evaluated in order to see a line or the union of a line and a surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1^2 + x_2^2$, we have $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = 0$ if and only if $x_1 = x_2 = 0$ (since $x_i^2$ are non-negative). This means that

$$ Z_{\mathbb{R}}(f) = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \, | \, x_1 = x_2 = 0 \} = \mathrm{span} \{ (0, 0, 1) \} $$

is indeed a line (the $z$-axis).

For $g(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_3^2 + x_2^2 - x_2^3$, we have

$$ Z_{\mathbb{R}}(g) = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \, | \, x_2^3 = x_2^2 + x_3^2 \} = \\ \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\, | \, x_2^3 = x_2^2 + x_3^2, x_2 \neq 0 \} \cup \{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\, | \, x_2^3 = x_2^2 + x_3^2, x_2 = 0 \} = A_1 \cup A_2. $$

The $A_2$ piece is a line $A_2 = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \, | \, x_2 = x_3 = 0 \}$ (the $x$-axis). To see that $A_1$ is a surface, note that

$$ \nabla g|_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)} = (0, 2x_2 - 3x_2^2, 2x_3) = (0, x_2(2 - 3x_2), 2x_3). $$

If we set $U = \{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \, | \, x_2 \neq 0 \}$ then $g|_{U}^{-1}(0) = A_1$ and $0$ is a regular value of $g|_U$ and so by the implicit function theorem, $A_1$ is a surface.